# designer wont accept my method mouse down

Tags: c#

I try to get the Heu value from where i click on an image, however I am doing something wrong and i am not sure what it is, it has to do with the designer file and how i call the function _mousedown of the image.

in my main.designer.cs file i have:

```
// pictureBox1
// 
this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(146, 30);
this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(640, 480);
this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 1;
this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;

//line below is not accepted ??  

this.pictureBox1.MouseDown += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox1_MouseDown);
```

in my main program i have :

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Drawing.Point Cursor = new System.Drawing.Point(e.X, e.Y);
        Color pixel = myImage.GetPixel(Cursor.X, Cursor.Y);
        textBoxH.Text =pixel.GetHue().ToString();
     }
```

The error i get is :

*'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox' does not contain a definition for 'pictureBox1_MouseDown' and no extension method 'pictureBox1_MouseDown' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox' could be found

are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

C:\projects\visual studio 2010\Projects\image\Main.Designer.cs**

Note i have included `using System;` above in my main program.

***UPDATE** * 
After compile i now get a different error (have not changed the code)

Error   1   No overload for 'pictureBox1_MouseDown' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

Comment: What is your question? What do you expect and what do you get?

Comment: On a glimpse your code seems just fine. Could post the error? It may help us discover where is the problem.

Comment: Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox' does not contain a definition for 'pictureBox1_MouseDown' and no extension method 'pictureBox1_MouseDown' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\projects\visual studio 2010\Projects\image\Main.Designer.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to my like you hand coded a change to your designer file.  If you did, stop doing that: designer generated code should not be touched as VS will screw with it.

Regardless, that's not the right definition for a mouse down event.

The following:

```
this.pictureBox1.MouseDown += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox1_MouseDown);
```

should be:

```
this.pictureBox1.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.pictureBox1_MouseDown);
```

Comment: how else would i get the mouse_down event to the picturebox ?

Comment: Wrong it did work, for debuging i had the mousedown code marked //

Comment: @user613326: Use the designer surface, click on the picturebox. Then go to properties, events and double click the mouse down event.

Comment: i dont have that in properties (using visual studio 2010 express)

Comment: Ah just found the lightning symbol, above properties, for events
haha :)